# Is "ræda in fossá est" an actual Latin saying/metaphor?

Tags: idiom, metaphora, saying

I heard this on a podcast the other day to mean that the conversation had gotten stuck. I looked it up and it seems to be a reference to the textbook *Ecce Rómání*, in which a cart gets stuck in a ditch for a while, apparently—given how many references there are to it online—to the amusement of decades' worth of Latin students. However, I couldn't find any references to it in any authentic Roman/Latin texts.

I'm wondering: is this an actual Latin saying/metaphor that the Romans or other Latin speakers used at any time in history? Or has it just become a thing because so many people learned Latin from *Ecce Rómání*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't really prove a negative, but Cassell's "Latin Dictionary" has quotes and references from ancient sources for almost every entry.  Neither `raeda` nor `fossa` contains a reference to this saying, despite having several other references.

I would go out on a limb and say that this was not a catch phrase for the ancients.

Comment: To support this, L&S don't mention such a phrase under either word, and searching PHI for [in fossa](http://latin.packhum.org/search?q=in+fossa) yields nothing relevant either.

Comment: Thanks, @JoelDerfner!  Also, thanks to @TKR for the additional lack of references.